# Logging into the Steam website

Tags: python, mechanize, python-requests, browser-automation, steam

I'm looking to make a script that'll log into the SteamPowered.com website, and then navigate to the account page. I wrote a script that takes the sales from that page and just adds it up. The issue is that I'd have to manually save the HTML to a file and then open that file. I was trying to do it with `requests` but I think Steam uses OpenID or something similar, and I couldn't log in. I then took a look at `mechanize` but I couldn't get passed the login screen due to captcha, as far as I can tell.

**What are the necessary steps I need to take to log into the Steam website, in Python?**

Here's the total sales counter if you're interested. This is the earlier version though, so if you have less than 6 sales on the system you need to handle the index errors and you won't be able to verify the total sales. http://pastebin.com/3CXBJUGe

---

**Update**: I started working with Selenium, and unless I get it to open a new tab inside my currently open browser, it pops up asking the user to input a code that Steam sends to their email. I think it'd be a lot harder than just asking  the user for the page of their purchase history like I had before.

Here's the Selenium code. It uses hardcoded Xpath, so you might want to change that.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "path\to\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url = r'https://store.steampowered.com/login/'
driver.get(url)

xpath = r'//*[@id="login_btn_signin"]/a'

INuser = driver.find_element_by_id('input_username')
INpass = driver.find_element_by_id('input_password')
LOGbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

#put in the user and pass into the 2 above elements, then click the last one

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Er, do you want Python to magically bypass or solve the CAPTCHA? Or do you want to find out how to use mechanize to display the CAPTCHA so you can solve it manually?

Comment: I've done some reading, and it seems like it's real easy  to grab the captcha id and get an image from the API right? But my question really is: is that the right way to go about it? I'm having some trouble with `mechanize` and there doesn't seem to be many tutorials around.

Comment: If you just want to add up all your spendings from the steam account by parsing the HTML, wouldn't a user javascript snippet or some other sort of browser extension be more appropriate?

Comment: That would probably be the more reasonable approach, but unfortunately I don't know anything other than Python.

Comment: Selenium has Python bindings.

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin Thanks, I've tried Selenium before, but it wasn't quite working out for me. I'll try that out after I fool around with mechanize some more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working for Steam? Or, are you just trying to automate the site? The point of the [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is that it could be solved only by human.

Comment: I don't believe that the Captcha is actually stopping me for sure, I'm just not sure  why I can't proceed past the login screen.